# magento 1.8 where to add cookie consent in admin panel

Tags: javascript, cookies, magento-1.7

I have a cookie consent pop that will popup .

I have placed it in  System-> Config-> Design-> Footer-> HTMl section-> < JSFiddleCode >

But i tried clearing all cookies and sessions, cleared magento cache too,
but pop up doesnt show up.

Is it the right place to keep, if i need the popup to appear in all the footer sections.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
"palette": {
"popup": {
"background": "#ffffff"
},
"button": {
"background": "transparent",
"text": "#dea724",
"border": "#dea724"
}
},
"position": "bottom-right",
"content": {
"dismiss": "Okay",
"href": "<your link>"
}
})});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out it that cookie has to enabled in admin side.

> To Allow Cookie restriction mode: System-> Configuration->Web-> Session and cookie mgt-> 
>   Select Yes for  "Cookie Restriction Mode"

And then cookie pop up appears on bottom of the page.